# Is an array limited in number within a given field in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using here that users put their Ids inside another user's array as likes.

I need to know if it limited or not. Also what is the best for that to use a collection for user's likes or array ?

[image]

Comment: I think this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-firestore-costs-8cb712473e83), might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit you need to be aware of is the maximum size of a single document, which is 1MB.  This is covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).  The size of the array isn't the issue - it's the sum of the sizes of all the values you put into it.  You should understand [how to calculate the size of a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size).

Your second question is a matter of opinion and is therefore [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  The best model for your data is going to depend on how you want to query the data and will vary from case to case.  But if your elements are ever going to exceed the max size of a document, it's clear that you should not use an array field to hold all the elements.

Comment: thanks a lot , i wasn't know about maximum size of a single document, which is 1MB